# Multithreading in Python script

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I have few datasets in the form of numpy.arrays, vectors and dictionaries. Let's call them *D*<sub>*i*</sub>, *i* = 1..4. Other than these, I have a csv file F1.csv that has only one column.

I have written a python code ***P*** that will read rows from F1.csv. For each row, using read operations on *Di*, it will generate some data that has to be written on F2.csv. This code is working fine and giving expected results.

However, *D*<sub>*i*</sub> are huge and ***P*** is using only one CPU core. How can I make P use two cores -- one core for the first half of F1.csv and other for the second half?

My code is too complex to be written here, therefore I am giving a toy version:

```
# Code for generating D1
  ...
# Code for generating D2
  ...
# Code for generating D3
  ...
# Code for generating D4
  ...

# P starts

F1 = csv.reader(open('data/F1.csv'), delimiter='\t')
F2 = open('data/F2.csv', 'wb')

for row in F1:
    toBeWritten = { ... some read operations on Di ... } #detailed code is given below in Edit 2

    F2.write(toBeWritten)

# P ends
```

How can I modify the code between "*# P starts*" and "*# P ends*" so that the threads read disjoint rows from F1.csv, calculate *toBeWritten* independently, and then write to F2.csv?

I am new to Python multi-threading, so an answer that simply modifies my code to accomplish the task will be highly appreciated.

Edit 1:

Please note that the bottleneck is generating the *toBeWritten* corresponding to each row of F2. *D<sub>1</sub>* is a 1.5M x 1.3M sparse matrix, read as scipy.sparse.lil_matrix. Generating *toBeWritten* involves adding some rows of this matrix. This addition is the real culprit!

Edit 2:

Actual code for generating *toBeWritten* is now included in the code below.

```
# D1 is a 1.5M x 1.3M sparse matrix, read as scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.
# D2 is a 1.5M x 111 matrix, read as numpy.array
# for row in F1:
    user_id = row[0]
    clust = D2[user_id, 110]
    neighbors = D2[ D2[:, 110] == clust][:,1]
    score = np.zeros(1300000)

    for neigh in neighbors:
        score = score + D1 [neigh, :] # the most expensive operation

    toBeWritten = np.argsort(score)[:,::-1].A[0,:]
```

Comment: Assuming you are using CPython, you should be aware of the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL): https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock.  The effect will vary depending on how much work you do with `numpy`, since that is not restricted by the GIL.

Comment: Are you sure the bottleneck isn't IO-related? Multiprocessing is unlikely to make a noticeable difference to your runtime if the limiting factor is reading/writing the data to disk rather than doing the actual processing.

Comment: @ali_m the bottleneck is not IO-related. The bottleneck is actually generating "toBeWritten" using the Di that already in the main memory.

Comment: @ali_m I have described the real overhead now. Can you suggest me a way other than multi-threading/processing to make it faster?

Comment: For one thing, arithmetic operations on LIL matrices are *slow* (see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html)) - you would probably be better off using a CSR matrix instead. You'll need to show your code if you want a proper answer that addresses your processing step. My general advice is to profile your code and focus on getting your single-threaded performance as good as possible before you consider switching to a parallel implementation. In my experience this is usually where the biggest and easiest performance gains can be made.

Comment: @ali_m, thanks for the suggestion. I have now included some code as well and have explicitly marked the most expensive operation.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if threads can help you with your specific problem but here you go:

```
# Code for generating D1
  ...
# Code for generating D2
  ...
# Code for generating D3
  ...
# Code for generating D4
  ...

# P starts

with open('data/F1.csv', 'rb') as csv_file, open('data/F2.csv', 'wb') as F2:
    F1 = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='\t')
    result = list()

    def do_work(lines):
        for line in lines:
            toBeWritten = { ... some read operations on Di ... }
            result.append(toBeWritten)

    data = list(F1)
    t0 = threading.Thread(target=do_work, args=(data[:len(data)/2], ))
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=do_work, args=(data[len(data)/2:], ))
    t0.start()
    t1.start()
    t0.join()
    t1.join()

    for line in result:
        F2.write(line)

# P ends
```

You might want to try multiprocessing if threads don't help.

Comment: I have described the real overhead now. Can you suggest me a way other than multi-threading/processing to make it faster? I feel multi-threading/processing will at max give me 2x speed-up which is not what I am looking for.